# AngularJS ng-model issues while repeating the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to send the parameters to control and I am struck in between and need help.

There are multiple types of question inside the ng-repeat i.e 'question' and I am iterating these. The problem is when there are two question with same question type. When I give input into one question the other question is also taking the same data. Kindly help me out with this.

Below is the form.

```html
<div ng-repeat="question in qgroup[grp_id].question" name="outerDiv">
        <div ng-if="question.question_type === 'short_text'" class="row form-group">
          <label class="control-label label-pad-top col-sm-6" for="short-text">{{question.name}}:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="f-name" name="shortText" class="form-control" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="data.answer.shortText">
          </div>
        </div>



        <div ng-if="question.question_type === 'date_format'" class="row form-group">
          <label class="control-label label-pad-top col-sm-6" for="short-text">{{question.name}}:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="d-type" name="date" class="form-control" id="date-type" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" ng-model="data.answer.date">
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: where is defined the "data" variable?

Comment: Not causing the problem necessarily, but you can't have the same ID more than once in a document.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the model you are using for the input is shared between questions of the same type.

A natural solution to this would be to put the answer onto the question object. i.e.

```
<input type="f-name" name="shortText" class="form-control" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="question.answer">
```

instead of

```
<input type="f-name" name="shortText" class="form-control" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="data.answer.shortText">
```